# Assign new ticket to logged in user

Tags: trac

In Trac is possible to set the "owner" for a new ticket to the logged in user ? 
I've tried with different value for `default_owner` in `trac.ini` but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From trac.edgewall.org authoritative documentation in [Trac tickets](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTickets) (wiki):

> default_owner: Name of the default owner. If set to the text "< default >" (the default value), the component owner is used.

So this is cannot help you for sure. There are a few more approaches left, depending on you Genshi template knowledge, Python skills etc. Your requirement is not hard to fulfill, but you cannot get it with stock Trac. You'll need to modify the (new) ticket template or add a relatively small plugin (tested with Trac-1.1.1):

```
import re
from trac.core import Component, implements
from trac.ticket.api import ITicketManipulator

class DefaultTicketOwnerManipulator(Component):
"""Set ticket owner to logged in user, if available."""

    implements(ITicketManipulator)

    def prepare_ticket(self, req, ticket, fields, actions):
        pass

    def validate_ticket(self, req, ticket):
        if not ticket['owner'] and req.authname:
            ticket['owner'] = req.authname
            # Optionally report-back manipulation, so require a second POST.
            # return [(None, "Owner set to self (%s)" % req.authname)]
        return []
```

Hint: Use commented-out 'return' in pre-last line to not alter owner silently right on save, good for test too.

Comment: [#2045](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/2045) will give us the flexibility to use workflow actions when transitioning to the new state. So we can look forward to that for Trac 1.2.

Comment: Further comments on the possible use-case supported by #2045: http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/2045#comment:38

Comment: I just came across [#7979](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/7979), in which this same feature was requested.

Comment: One more possibility: [AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin) has a `set_owner_to_reporter` field that will accomplish *setting the owner to the currently logged in user*.

Comment: This ability to specify actions when creating a ticket is implemented on the trunk of Trac now. It will be included in release 1.1.3, scheduled for Jan 1st, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The following applies to Trac 1.1.3 or later, which is scheduled for release on 1st Jan 2015. It is implemented on the Trac trunk, which we do a pretty good job of keeping stable. The default *create* workflow actions are:

```
create = <none> -> new
create.default = 1
create_and_assign = <none> -> assigned
create_and_assign.label = assign
create_and_assign.operations = may_set_owner
create_and_assign.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
```

To have the `create` action assign to the current user, just add:

```
create.operations = set_owner_to_self
```

Renaming the action might be appropriate, putting the ticket into either the `assigned` or `accepted` state:

```
create_and_accept = <none> -> accepted
create_and_accept.label = accept
create_and_accept.default = 1
create_and_accept.operations = set_owner_to_self
```